# Is this exotic set an open set?

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some positive integer $k$. Consider the following set (for some positive integer $n$):

$$\bigcup_{x_1,\cdots,x_n \in U} \left( (U \setminus\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}) \times \{x_1\} \times \{x_2\} \times \cdots \times \{x_n\} \right).$$

Is this an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{k(n+1)}$ (under the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}^{k(n+1)}$)? If so, what is the number of connected components? How do I go about proving this?

For instance, when $n = 1, k = 1,$ and $U = \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left((\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}) \times \{x\} \right) = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \Delta_{\mathbb{R}^2},$$
where $\Delta_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ is the diagonal of $\mathbb{R}^2$, is an open set (since it is the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$ space with the line $y = x$ removed). The resulting set has two connected components.

Furthermore, I'm not sure if this is related to some specific concept. For instance, when I tried to search for related materials, concepts like "foliations" and "fiber bundles" came up.

Any help will be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Well, if you call $X$ your set, then $(t_0,\cdots,t_n)\in(\Bbb R^k)^{n+1}\in X$ if and only if all the $t_j$-s are in $U$ and, for all $j\ge1$, $t_j\ne t_0$. In other words, $X=U^{n+1}\cap\bigcap_{j=1}^n \{(t_0,\cdots, t_n)\in(\Bbb R^k)^{n+1}\,:\, t_0\ne t_j\}$ which is open in $(\Bbb R^k)^{n+1}$.

Comment: That is helpful - thanks! I probably didn't think this through enough...  If you put it as an answer I'll accept it - thanks! I guess counting the number of connected components might not be as straightforward...? (Since this might depend on if $0$ is in $U$?)

Comment: Provided that my ability to do anything doesn't mean much, I don't presume to be able to count the number of connected components even for $U=\Bbb R^k$.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense - thanks anyway!